# Avoiding Anemic Domain

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a column in a database that looks like "Country/Province/City", e.g. "Canada/Ontario/Toronto".  I need to split those and map them into 3 separate Java Bean properties.

I am wondering where best to do this?

(1) DAO as the rows are retrieved
(2) Domain (Bean) as the setters are getters are called
(3) A SQL function to parse the rows in the query
(4) Using the ResultSetExtractor

I am leaning towards #2 or #4 since the "Anemic Domain" anti-pattern seems to indicate that the Bean is an appropriate place for this.

Comment: @Gabe Data Access Object. A standard pattern used in the world of business software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, the best place to do this is the database. I would split this column into 3 columns in the table, and store one information by column.

If this is really not an option for legacy reasons, I would indeed do it in the domain object directly. This is behavior that can be encapsulated directly in the domain object without any impact on the other entities.

Comment: The reason why I want to avoid the DB is that I am concerned that the delimited path items may change to include more or less nodes, and I want the flexibility to adapt.  I.e the 2nd node may not always be Province, at least in some cases, so I may need to apply logic to determine that.  The more I look at this, I like using the ResultSetExtractor (Spring JDBC).  It isn't quite the Bean, and it isn't quite the DAO.  It sits in the middle of the two.

Comment: The more complex the path becomes, the more you'll need a normalized data model, IMHO. Else you'll end up storing XML, JSON or a serialized object in a single column, and you won't be able to query your data anymore. One column = one information.

Comment: If the option to redesign the DB is still open to you, OP, you should **definitely** prefer that. Nothing can beat the advantages of having a well-structured model. I think we should discuss other options only failing that.

Comment: BTW How come the `ResultSetExtractor` is not inside your DAO? On projects I have worked on this has always been the case.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - I am using the following example as a basis for design.   
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?51731-JDBCTemplate-or-SimpleJDBCTemplate-example-using-ResultSetExtractor

Comment: I see. I think that piece of code is slightly out of context. What we typically do is make that `ResultSetExtractor` implementation either an inner class of the DAO class, or even an anonymous class inside the method -- depending on how far it will be reused. It is not customary to put it in its own file. But even when it's in a separate file, it still counts as part of the DAO layer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree with you; You could argue that the domain entity doesn't need to be influenced by the data representation.
Would you consider having a bean with setters and getters if your database layout had been different?
I your answer is 'no', then you probably don't want that option.

Personally, I think that if you have a data-access layer, that's part of its job- to transaform data representation into domain representation.

Comment: The qualification of the Anemic Domain as an anti-pattern has not lived up to reality. In business software you in fact want a complete separation of functions and data model. OOP doesn't have much to offer to business logic. It mostly bogs it down, in fact, by requiring each function to be dispatched on an object, resulting in huge and unmaintainable object graphs. Nobody even tries to build them without relegating the graph building to autowiring IoC frameworks.

Comment: once again- you're stating your opinions as facts.

Comment: +1 the DAO is the right place to do this translation. Domain objects should reflect the real business model, not the persistence model (which in many cases is way off due to legacy reasons).

Answer (score 0):

If this a JPA `@Entity` then I would map a private String directly to the DB column, then make public getters that wrap access to it.  That way, consumers of your domain model are isolated from the internal/DB representation of the concatenated string.  Alternatively, you could do the translation in a `@PostLoad` callback.  (Reverse translation on persist could be done on a `@PrePersist` callback.)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't your 1. and 4. in fact the same solution? You'd use the `ResultSetExtractor` inside your DAO code, I presume. Using an SQL function is not a bad idea since it's reusable from other technologies, but there's the maintenance issue.

I wouldn't recommend delaying the parsing till getting time since it's not good from the performance side and can make your life complicated when doing other tasks with those fields. It would be cleaner if your beans already had the three fields.

Comment: Yes, if my DAO and Extractor were in the same class, but I've separated them - rightly or wrongly.  Please see my response to your question above.